# pandas (python) - reshaping two columns into one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am working on a pandas project and I am looking to turn:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9qua.png)

into something like this:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtKTg.png)

I have tried to use melt, without success and I am out of ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Bu using `stack` ..

```
df.set_index('label').stack()
Out[160]: 
label      
a      hign    100
       low       1
b      hign    111
       low       2
dtype: int64
```

and `melt`

```
df.melt('label').set_index(['label','variable'])
Out[162]: 
                value
label variable       
a     hign        100
b     hign        111
a     low           1
b     low           2
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'label':['a','b'],'low':[1,2],'hign':[100,111]})
```